# A clojure friendly library for playing sounds

Tags: clojure, audio

I'm looking for an easy to program library for infrequently playing sounds (notifications and the like) from a clojure function.

edit: like this

```
(use 'my.sound.lib') 
(play-file "filename")
(beep-loudly)
(bark-like-a-dog)
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, with the question now including an API wishlist... ;-)

You can use [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) for MP3 playback on the JVM. On Ubuntu it's packaged up as libjlayer-java. There's a simple example of use in Java [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/faq/mp3/mp3.html). A Clojure wrapper:

```
(defn play-file [filename & opts]
  (let [fis (java.io.FileInputStream. filename)
        bis (java.io.BufferedInputStream. fis)
        player (javazoom.jl.player.Player. bis)]
    (if-let [synchronously (first opts)]
      (doto player
        (.play)
        (.close))
      (.start (Thread. #(doto player (.play) (.close)))))))
```

Use `(play-file "/path/to/file.mp3")` to play back an mp3 fly in a separate thread, `(play-file "/path/to/file.mp3" true)` if you'd prefer to play it on the current thread instead. Tweak to your liking. Supply your own loud beep and barking dog mp3. ;-)

For a load beep and the like, you could also use MIDI... Perhaps this [blog entry](http://blog.jalat.com/2009/06/simple-midi-wrapper-library-in-clojure.html) will be helpful if you choose to try.

Also, the link from my original answer may still be helpful in your tweaking: [Java Sound Resources: Links](http://www.jsresources.org/links.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since year 2010 there appeared at least three libraries for audio playback, manipulation, visualization and saving.

## clj-audio

A general-purpose audio library built on top of the Java Sound API. Has minimal amount of dependencies, but the project looks pretty abandoned.

Reference in `project.clj` (the second one is required for playing MP3 files):

```
[org.clojars.beppu/clj-audio "0.3.0"]
[com.googlecode.soundlibs/mp3spi "1.9.5.4"]
```

Usage example:

```
(require '[clj-audio.core :refer :all])

;; Play an MP3 file
(-> (->stream "bell.mp3")
    decode
    play)

;; Playing synthesized sounds is an experimental feature for the library
```

More details: https://github.com/beppu/clj-audio

## Dynne

A simple and easy to use choice. Has tons of dependencies.

Reference in `project.clj`:

```
[org.craigandera/dynne "0.4.1"]
```

Usage example:

```
(require '[dynne.sampled-sound :refer :all])

;; Play an MP3 file
(play (read-sound "bell.mp3"))

;; Play a synthesized sound
(play (sinusoid 1.0 440))
```

More details: https://github.com/candera/dynne

## Overtone

An advanced option that relies on the [SuperCollider](https://supercollider.github.io/) synthesis engine. I guess it'd be an overkill for just playing notifications, but I'm referring it here for sake of completeness.

More details: https://github.com/overtone/overtone